# Constraint fails but record exists

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`league_ranking` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `position` INT NULL,
  `team_id` INT NULL,
  `season_id` INT NULL,
  `round_id` INT NULL,
  `competition_id` INT NULL,
  `group_id` INT NULL,
  `played_matches` INT NULL,
  `wins` INT NULL,
  `draws` INT NULL,
  `losses` INT NULL,
  `goals_for` INT NULL,
  `goals_against` INT NULL,
  `goals_difference` INT NULL,
  `points` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `FK_competition_groups_form_ranking_group_id_idx` (`group_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_team_league_ranking_teamd_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`team` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_round_league_ranking_round_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`round` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_league_ranking_competition_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`competition` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_groups_league_ranking_group_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`competition_groups` (`group_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`competition` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `country_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `link` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `id_idx` (`country_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_country_competition_country_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`country` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I'm trying to add a record inside `league_ranking` table which have different `FK`. I defined a record inside `competition` table that have this fields values:

```
id | country_id | name | link
13       89       foo     test
```

I add the record in this way:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO league_ranking (position, team_id, season_id, 

round_id, competition_id, " +
"group_id, played_matches, wins, draws, losses, goals_for, goals_against, goals_difference, points) " +
"VALUES (@position, @team_id, @season_id, @round_id, @competition_id, @group_id, @played_matches, " +
"@wins, @draws, @losses, @goals_for, @goals_against, @goals_difference, @points)";

MySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, MySqlConnection);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", tbl.Position);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team_id", tbl.TeamId);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@season_id", seasonId);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@round_id", roundId);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@competition_id", compId);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@group_id", groupId);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@played_matches", tbl.PlayedMatches);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wins", tbl.Wins);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@draws", tbl.Draws);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@losses", tbl.Losses);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@goals_for", tbl.GoalsFor);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@goals_against", tbl.GoalsAgainst);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@goals_difference", tbl.GoalDifference);
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@points", tbl.Points);
MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get this error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`league_ranking`, CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_league_ranking_competition_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `competition` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)'

now the value of `competition_id` id `13` and the record exist inside the `competition` table, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems while defining foreign keys in table `mydb.league_ranking`, you used wrong columns from it with reference to the right columns in `competition` table.

For example `id` in `league` table should not be used but `competition_id` to refer with `id` of  `competition` table.

Similarly, with other columns as well.

Redefine `league` table accordingly, and the try your insert statements.